I'm bulding my own Operating System, but when I run it, i got this: Boot failed: could not read the boot disk

A got this when I run my OS.
It's say: Boot failed: could not read the boot disk
But in my bootloader.asm, I defined this for read the disk:
mov bx, 0x1000  ;Load the core
mov ah, 0x02    ;Bios func for read the disk

And this is the code of the bootloarder.asm:
; bootloader.asm
[org 0x7c00]            ; Le code commence à l'adresse 0x7C00 (adresse standard pour le bootloader)

start:
    cli                 ; Désactiver les interruptions
    mov ax, 0x07C0      ; Charger l'adresse du bootloader en mémoire
    add ax, 288         ; Ajuster le segment de pile
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096

    ; Afficher un caractère à l'écran (test)
    mov ah, 0x0E        ; Fonction BIOS pour afficher un caractère
    mov al, 'B'         ; Caractère à afficher
    int 0x10            ; Interruption vidéo BIOS

    ; Charger le noyau (1 secteur) à partir du disque
    mov bx, 0x1000      ; Charger le noyau à l'adresse 0x1000 en mémoire
    mov ah, 0x02        ; Fonction BIOS pour lire le disque
    mov al, 1           ; Lire 1 secteur
    mov ch, 0           ; Cylindre 0
    mov dh, 0           ; Tête 0
    mov cl, 2           ; Secteur 2 (le premier secteur est le bootloader)
    int 0x13            ; Interruption BIOS : lecture du disque

    jc disk_error       ; Si erreur (carry flag), sauter à la gestion d'erreur
    jmp 0x1000:0000     ; Sauter au noyau chargé en mémoire à l'adresse 0x1000

disk_error:
    ; Afficher un message d'erreur si le disque ne peut pas être lu
    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov al, 'E'
    int 0x10
    cli
    hlt

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0  ; Remplir jusqu'à 510 octets
dw 0xAA55                ; Signature du bootloader

Here the linker.ld:
/* linker.ld */
ENTRY(kmain)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x1000;
    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }
    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }
    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
    }
}

Here the kernel.c:
/* kernel.c */
#define VIDEO_MEMORY 0xb8000
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 80
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 25
#define WHITE_ON_BLACK 0x07

int cursor_x = 35;  // Position du curseur dans le carré (horizontale)
int cursor_y = 12;  // Position du curseur dans le carré (verticale)

void clear_screen() {
    char *video_memory = (char *)VIDEO_MEMORY;
    for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT * 2; i += 2) {
        video_memory[i] = ' ';
        video_memory[i + 1] = WHITE_ON_BLACK;
    }
}

void draw_square() {
    char *video_memory = (char *)VIDEO_MEMORY;

    // Dessiner un carré au centre de l'écran (10x5)
    for (int y = 10; y < 15; y++) {
        for (int x = 30; x < 50; x++) {
            int offset = (y * SCREEN_WIDTH + x) * 2;
            if (y == 10 || y == 14 || x == 30 || x == 49) {
                video_memory[offset] = '#';  // Bords du carré
            } else {
                video_memory[offset] = ' ';  // Intérieur du carré
            }
            video_memory[offset + 1] = WHITE_ON_BLACK;
        }
    }
}

void put_char(char c) {
    int offset = (cursor_y * SCREEN_WIDTH + cursor_x) * 2;
    char *video_memory = (char *)VIDEO_MEMORY;

    video_memory[offset] = c;
    video_memory[offset + 1] = WHITE_ON_BLACK;

    cursor_x++;
    if (cursor_x > 48) {
        cursor_x = 35;
        cursor_y++;
    }
}

void kmain() {
    clear_screen();
    draw_square();

    // Exemple d'écriture dans le carré
    put_char('H');
    put_char('e');
    put_char('l');
    put_char('l');
    put_char('o');
}

And finaly the makefile:
# Définir les fichiers source
C_SOURCES = kernel.c
OBJECTS = $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)

# Toutes les étapes : création de l'image OS et de l'image ISO
all: os-image myos.iso

# Combiner le bootloader et le noyau pour créer une image OS binaire
os-image: bootloader.bin kernel.bin
    cat bootloader.bin kernel.bin > os-image

# Assembler le bootloader (en binaire)
bootloader.bin: bootloader.asm
    nasm -f bin bootloader.asm -o bootloader.bin

# Compiler le noyau en fichier objet
kernel.o: kernel.c
    gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o

# Lier le noyau (création de kernel.bin)
kernel.bin: kernel.o
    ld -m elf_i386 -T linker.ld -o kernel.bin kernel.o

# Créer l'image ISO bootable avec xorriso
.PHONY: myos.iso
myos.iso: os-image
    xorriso -as mkisofs -b os-image -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o myos.iso os-image


# Nettoyer les fichiers générés
clean:
    rm -f *.bin *.o os-image myos.iso

Thanks a lots of the help guys !
I tried to read the core with this:
mov bx, 0x1000      ; Load the core
mov ah, 0x02        ; Read the disk with the BIOS
mov al, 1           ; Read sect 1
mov ch, 0           ; Cylinder 0
mov dh, 0           ; Head 0
mov cl, 2           ; Sect 2 (the first sect is the bootloader)
int 0x13            ; Interuption BIOS => for read the disk

But it's still don't works

The error is unrelated. It's just telling you that neither the floppy nor the hard disk can be read which is normal since you boot an ISO. Note that your code will not work because you try to call 32 bit code from 16 bit mode. Furthermore you jump to 1000:0000 but your kernel is linked to offset 1000. And you don't set es so no telling where the code will end up at anyway (int 13/02 uses es:bx)

I try with this:
[BITS 16]
But it's still don't work

Irrelevant, that is the default for nasm. The kernel you compiled with gcc is 32 bit code. Additionally, as I said, it's linked to the wrong address and possibly even loaded to an unknown address.

See How to make the kernel for my bootloader? - Michael Petch's answer is excellent and covers lots of common problems, and has a working example bootloader and 32-bit kernel built from C, with build commands.

Possibly xorriso -as mkisofs option -boot-info-table is to blame.
It causes xorriso to overwrite bytes 8 to 63 in the boot image.
Larger boot images use these bytes to locate themselves on the optical
boot medium and to load more of themselves than just the 4 blocks of
512 bytes, which they trust any BIOS to be able to load.
So try xorriso -as mkisofs without option -boot-info-table.
Better omit option -boot-load-size 4 , too, until your bootimage becomes
too large for getting loaded by your BIOS. (Then you will have to study
ISOLINUX or GRUB for their preparation and use of bytes 8 to 63 in the
boot image.)
